# Color Shifted Images via Imagemagick?

Tags: colors, imagemagick, png, shift

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to create a similar effect to that below using imagemagick? I doubt it matters, but I'm working with png images.

[image: color shift example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
convert -size 800x600 caption:"SOME TEXT" -compose darken \
   \( -clone 0 -fill "rgb(227,90,130)" -opaque black -roll +10+0 \) -composite \
   \( -clone 0 -fill "rgb(71,160,200)" -opaque black -roll -10+0 \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Or do you mean you need the Bakewell Tart dragged toothpick effect too? https://media.bakingmad.com/app_/responsive/BakingMad/media/content/Recipes/Tarts/Bakewell-Tart/1-Luis-Troyano-Bakewell-Tart-WEB.jpg?w=1680

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this in ImageMagick uses composite -stereo.

Input:

[image]

```
composite -stereo -20+0 test.png test.png result1.png
```

[image]

But this is less flexible in the color choice than Mark Setchell's method.